# Error in styles.xml in android-support-v7-mediarouter

Tags: android, xml

Following is the styles.xml file for the android-support-v7-mediarouter.

```
<resources>
    <style name="Widget.MediaRouter.MediaRouteButton"
            parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">56dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/mr_media_route_button_content_description</item>
        <item name="externalRouteEnabledDrawable">@drawable/mr_ic_media_route_holo_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MediaRouter.Light.MediaRouteButton"
            parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">56dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/mr_media_route_button_content_description</item>
        <item name="externalRouteEnabledDrawable">@drawable/mr_ic_media_route_holo_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But I am getting lots of no resource found errors, Some of them are:

```
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:122: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:125: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:133: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:137: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:141: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:44: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:72: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:76: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:112: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:116: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:92: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-04-05 10:03:14 - SplashActivity] /home/sahil/workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat/res/values-v14/styles_base.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
```

I am trying to get [QuickBlox chat sample to work](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample).
**EDIT:**Versions:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you included the `mediarouter` library into your Android project? The library is located here, assuming you have already installed the Android SDK: `..\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\mediarouter`

Comment: @ChuongPham Yes I did that by project->properties->source->link source-> path to mediarouter.. But got all these errors..

Comment: Check my answer below to see if it helps. Note: You may need to delete your current reference to the `mediarouter` library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Eclipse`, to share the `mediarouter` library across multiple Android projects, do the following:

1. In Eclipse, select **File | Import | Existing Projects into workspace**. click **Next**.
2. Click **Browse**, and browse to the directory of Android appcompat directory. The default directory should be: `..\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\mediarouter\`.
3. Click **Finish** to add the new project.
4. Select the **Properties** tab of an Android project.
5. In the **Properties** screen, select the **Android** option (on the left pane), then click **Add**, and select the **mediarouter** library from the list.
6. Click **OK** to save the changes.

**IMPORTANT**: Repeat the above steps to add the `appcompat` and `gridlayout` libraries into your Android projects as these libraries are required by the `mediarouter` library. Once the appcompat and gridlayout libraries are added into the workspace, add the appcompat and gridlayout libraries to the mediarouter project by performing steps 4 to 6 above and substituting the appcompat/gridlayout name where required.

Whereas to *embed* the `mediarouter` library in each of your Android project, just copy the JAR files from the mediarouter's `libs` folder into your project's `libs` folder. You also need to copy the libs from the `appcompat` and `gridlayout` folders to your project's `libs` folder, too!

Comment: +1 :) That helped fix lots of import errors in the .java files but the styles.xml still shows the same errors..
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'. styles.xml /SplashActivity/res/values line 4 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: BDW i embed them all into my projects lib folder.

Comment: Have you tried the shared option instead of the embed option? Note: The shared option also include resources (styles.xml) so this will resolve the issue that you encountered.

Comment: Earlier I was using the shared option but the styles.xml file in the mediarouter project folder itself shows these errors.

Comment: Use the shared option, then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Anothing you need to be careful is that you MUST have the same Android SDK and ADT installed. Mismatch versions can cause unpredictable errors.

Comment: In Eclipse, to check for Android versions installed, select **Help | About Eclipse and click the **Android Open Source Project** icon. Also, The `mediarouter` library project depends on the `appcompat` library project, so you may need to import the appcompat library as well.

Comment: Add the **appcompat** library to **mediarouter** library by repeating steps 4 to 6 above. If you get errors like `PaddingStart`, `PaddingEnd`, etc is because they are only available from API 17 onwards. To overcome this error, open your mediarouter's `project.properties` file and change to `target=android-17`, or `target=android-18` or `target=android-19` (latest API released for Android).

Answer (score 7):

android media router depends on **appcompat** v7 library.
to resolve this issue correctly, add **appcompat** as a dependency for your "**android-support-v7-mediarouter**" library project and then add the media-router as a dependency for your own project...

more like your project depends on **android-support-v7-mediarouter** which depends on **appcompat_v7**

old question, late response, but hope it helps someone.
Took me some time to figure it out.

:)