# Referencing external project

Tags: android, reference, noclassdeffounderror

I have Android projects A and B, where Project B should reference project A. To accomplish that I did the following:

- Mark A as "isLibrary" and added it to project B --> noClassdeFoundException
- Added B under "Order and Export": A is checked and listed as first --> same exception

What else can I do?

Comment: Perhaps this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876747/error-in-styles-xml-in-android-support-v7-mediarouter/22877000#22877000) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by exporting Project A in a .jar-file (but without the AndroidManifest!), then importing that jar-File in Project B.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problems with google maps utility library yesterday and i fixed my problems by adding the jar of the library  to my libs folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right-click on B, click on Properties, select Android and then click "Add" in the Library sub-category and then add A to it.